# How to crawl markup with PHP, check if images exists and replace non-existing paths?

Tags: php

I have some markup which I need to crawl for images, and check if the images exists in the paths they have specified. If an image does not exists in location A, the path should be replaced with location B.

I'm wondering what would be the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: is it your markup or why do you need to do it that way? Why can't you check if the images exist BEFORE generating the markup?

Comment: Because the markup isn't generated by PHP, it's hand written. The markup is grabbed by PHP and then ran in another location, thus the image paths are different. The reason I don't want to use absolute paths or just change every path is that I want to retain simple "overloading" of the images on application basis; if the application doesn't have picture X, then redirect the path to common location, where all the default pictures are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). It is quite easy to use. Here's an example (which probably won't work, but you get the idea):

```
<?php

$document = simplexml_load_file('dah_file.html');

foreach ($document->children() as $child)
{
  if !file_exists($child['src'])
  {
    $child['src'] = 'path/to/image.png';
  }
}

print($document->asXml());

?>
```

Comment: And he can use file_get_contents($image_url) to check if the file exists.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about DOM. I use that a lot more than SimpleXML, but I fell away from coding PHP for a few months. I wish they would've chosen a catchier name for the best DOM parser...

Comment: Ahh. The DOMDocument seems like it's exactly what I need! Except that the DOMDocument stuffs DOCTYPE, html and body tags there, when I'm loading just document fragments... Markup is then JSON encoded into the document and transferred to the requesting client, in many cases this doubles the markup payload (when the markup is really simple), which isn't that brilliant, especially as the app is targeted for mobile use, where every byte counts.

Comment: Solved it with simple hack of adding extra DIV wrapper and just taking the contents of that DIV.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions here. Make a regular expression to match the `src` attribute of `<img>` tags and use it in [Preg_Replace_Callback](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) function.

Something like this (more or less pseudo code):

```
$htmlContent = Preg_Replace_Callback (
    '/<img src="(.*)"/is',
    function ( $matches ) {
        if ( ImageExists ( $matches[1] ) )
            return $matches[1];
        else
            return '/path/to/some/other/image.jpg';
    },
    $htmlContent
);
```

You'll have to provide the `ImageExists()` function off course, and a correct regex.

Comment: This is unreliable. What if the images are not written exactly like in your pattern?

Comment: I also agree: what happens if there is an `alt=` attribute before the `src=`? You would have to include that too... This *would* work though if the HTML markup is consistent throughout all of the documents

Comment: This sounds like it would be just what I need. Awsum! However, is there a way to get the pattern to catch the src even though there would be alt, id etc. tags before the src? Sadly, I'm rather useless myself when it comes to regular expressions.. :/

Comment: @all : I said you'd have to roll your own regular expression. That was just an example :)